# Restoring a database on multiple server architecture with two front end servers

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database

I am having a multiserver architecture with two front end servers. I want to restore a content database in one of the web application and it should reflect on both the site collections.

But when i restore the database only one site collections loads while the other one throws an error. It does not load.

What should be possible approach to restore the database. Awaiting your suggestions.

Comment: Please provide the error messages you're receiving.

Comment: the error is site could not be loaded.The normal error when you cant reach a particular site.

Comment: Are you sure that both site collections were in the same database?  Did you receive any errors when you mounted the DB to SharePoint?  In Central Admin when you go to "View All Site Collections" do you see the two sites collections or just the one that you are able to load?